# eclipse creating new package gives source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am a beginner in java and eclipse. I created a class in default package which works fine. But when I move this class to a new package and add package name at the beginning, it gives error. To understand the cause of the problem, I tried to -

1. Copy the same code and add package name at the top.
2. Right click class > Refactor > Move and then select my package to move the class.
3. Drag and drop the class in my new package.
   But none of this things works and I get "Source not found" error.

FYI, the class can be found in the following link-
http://pastebin.com/RdtjPc3R

I think the way I am calling the PApplet. main is not correct. Can anyone please help to resolve this?

I am using eclipse 4.5.2

Comment: Please check that all done as here https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

Comment: I checked that. But there is no instruction what to do when you create a custom package to run the applet. Anyway thanks for the link.